# Join two Select Statements into a single row when one select has n amount of entries?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible in SQL Server to take two select statements and combine them into a single row without knowing how many entries one of the select statements got?

I've been looking around at various Join solutions but they all seem to work on the basis that the amount of columns is predetermined. I have a case here where one table has a determined amount of columns (t1) and the other table have an undetermined amount of entries (t2) which all use a key that matches one entry in t1.

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | ... |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | John | ... |
+----+------+-----+
```

And

```
+-------------+----------------+
| activity_id | account_number |
+-------------+----------------+
| 1           | 12345467879    |
| 1           | 98765432515    |
| ...         | ...            |
| ...         | ...            |
+-------------+----------------+
```

The number of account numbers belonging to the first query is unknown.

After the query it would become:

```
+----+------+-----+----------------+------------------+-----+------------------+
| id | name | ... | account_number | account_number_2 | ... | account_number_n |
+----+------+-----+----------------+------------------+-----+------------------+
|  1 | John | ... |    12345467879 |      98765432515 | ... | ...              |
+----+------+-----+----------------+------------------+-----+------------------+
```

So I don't know how many account numbers could be associated with the id beforehand.

Comment: If you can provide sample data and expected output, it will be easier to answer

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yep, just did I hope :D

Comment: Yes, it's called a dynamic pivot and there are a lot of already answered questions about this.   Google `Dynamic Pivot in SQL Server.`

Comment: @TabAlleman Alright I'll try that. Thanks.